# jQuery adding new DOM elements having attributes within an element of specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a `methodToCreate` in jQuery which could be written as

```
    $("#someId").methodToCreate("tagName", ".className");
```

where an element with tag `tagName` would be added and given a class `className` and that too inside a specific element which would have an id `someId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out such function doesn't exist, but you could always create one .

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.methodToCreate= function(tagName,className,id) {
  $(id).append("<"+tagName+" "+"class="+"\'"+className+"\'>"+"SampleContent"+"</"+tagName+">");
  return this;
}; 
})( jQuery );
```

and you can call this whenever you want in the following manner :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).methodToCreate('p','sampleClass','#someId');
});
```

Using this function(`methodToCreate`) you can dynamically pass the `tagName` , `className` and `id` of the element that you want to append to.

Here is the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/varunsinghal65/udrxeg9m/1/#&togetherjs=TBEnLAnNzJ

Answer (score 2):

```
$("<tag></tag>").addClass("className").attr({id: 'someId'}).appendTo( "body" )
```

Here's and example setting all the attributes individually.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can create an element

```
var el = $('<tagName class="className"/>');
```

and then add it to a container

```
$('#someId').append(el);
```

Comment: Yeah that involves two steps. I was hoping if there is a way this could be achieved in just one step as mentioned in the question. But thanks for the input.

Comment: You can also just do
$('#someId').append('<tagName class="className"/>');

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#someId').append('<tagname class="className"></tagname>');
```

if you have the class stored in a variable (for example `myClass`) don't forget to quote it like this:

```
$('#someId').append('<tagname class="' + myClass + '"></tagname>');
```

Answer (score 0):

No that method does not exist, but you can  use **[.appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)**

like:

```
 $("<tagName class='className'></tagName>").appendTo("#someId");
```

Hope it helps.